# SSL for domain, including subdomains

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have a domain, `example.com`. From that, I have these:

- blog.example.com
- api.example.com
- books.example.com

I have acquired SSL cert for root domain and its subdomains.

And I want the redirections to be like so:

- http://example.com        => https://example.com
- http://blog.example.com   => https://blog.example.com
- http://books.example.com  => https://books.example.com

This is my `example.com` nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    root /home/django/khophi;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    include /etc/nginx/globalssl.conf; //ssl config
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

nginx conf for `blog.example.com`

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl; // now listens for https

        root /var/www/html/blog;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name blog.example.com;

        #include /etc/nginx/globalssl.conf;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        // error pages

        location ~ \.php$ {
                //php specific things
        }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       server_name blog.example.com;
       return 301 https://blog.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

`books.example.com` follows similar structure as `blog.example.com` conf

**What happens With the above setup?**

- Visit to `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com` (just as I want
- Visit to `http://blog.example.com` redirects to `https://blog.example.com` **BUT**, shows page of `https://example.com`

In my case, I want:

- `example.com` to remain as `default_server`
- `http://example.com` to redirect to `https://example.com`
- **ALL** http:// requested subdomains to redirect to their respective https:// versions
- if a subdomain is requested which doesn't exist, it should redirect to default_server (https://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `return`, i use `rewrite` instead on the redirection server block on the main domain and its subdomains, like so:

```
// blog.example.com

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.example.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

// example.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

[This link helped](https://blog.notmyhostna.me/nginx-wildcard-ssl-and-subdomains/)